# Excel how to extract line breaks in one cell into separate columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am having difficulty trying to get the text from cells A2:A16 to go into separate columns. So basically if Cell A2 has 3 line breaks of text then place them into cells B2,C2,D2, e.c.t. I have tried using Text to Columns but this has not worked. It only keeps the first bullet points. The image below is an example of how I want the formula to work. If there is any VBA or formulas that could work.

**How I want my data to show**

[image: Excel bullet points separated into columns]

[Excel Data DropBox Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwkrno7hibcr3bt/ProductData.xlsx?dl=0)

So after an hour of researching, I managed to come up with a solution by tweaking and editing some VBA code. Due to Text to columns method not working the code below worked a charm. Once you select cell A2 and run the macro it will extract all line breaks and place them in columns.

```
Sub splittext()
 'splits Text active cell using ALT+10 char as separator
    Dim splitVals As Variant
    Dim totalVals As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 1000
      splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))
      totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
      Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using a Markdown Tables Generator, or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hi Ron, I have just added some data that I am having issues with. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after an hour of researching, I managed to come up with a solution by tweaking and editing some VBA code. Due to Text to columns method not working the code below worked a charm. Once you select cell A2 and run the macro it will extract all line breaks and place them in columns.

```
Sub splittext()
 'splits Text active cell using ALT+10 char as separator
    Dim splitVals As Variant
    Dim totalVals As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 1000
      splitVals = Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))
      totalVals = UBound(splitVals)
      Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 1 + totalVals)).Value = splitVals
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Next i
End Sub
```

[Image of context placed into columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er6l1.gif)

Comment: You will find that each "split" has a trailing Carriage Return CHR(13) character (assuming your data is identical to what you uploaded).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this lengthy formula:

```
=IF(COLUMN()-3<LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),"")),MID(LEFT($A2,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),COLUMN()-1))-1,LEN($A2))),IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),COLUMN()-2))+1,1),1000),"")
```

It can be broken down into several parts:

`LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),""))` gives the number of newlines in the cell (`CHAR(10)` is a newline). As long as the current column minus 3 (B1 cell is column 2, a cell with 2 lines will have 1 newline, it will stop at column 3, where 3-3<1 is true, and the next column 4 will be false)

`LEFT($A2,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),COLUMN()-1))-1,LEN($A2)))` gives all the text from beginning to the nth bullet we need

`MID(above ,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(10),CHAR(1),COLUMN()-2))+1,1),1000)` gets the text as from the (n-1)th bullet until the end of the line.

I uploaded the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/014l4y9vtuaid1z/ProductData.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Text to columns was the right way. Here is a detailed instruction to achieve what you want:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2211-excel-split-cell-by-carriage-return.html

Basically you need to define the other delimiter as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and then select your target range in the next window

Comment: I have already used that website and followed it exactly. It doesn't work and I have tried it on multiple occasions. I need some formula or VBA. I could pass you a snipit of the data and see if it works your end? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Some data would help

Comment: I have just added the data to the question. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter is a combination of `Carriage Return` and `Line Feed` `Chr(13) Chr(10)`.

If you have Excel 2010 or later, you can use `Power Query` or `Data Get & Transform` to do the split as they provide the options for using that combination as a delimiter.

If you are using an earlier version, you can do this either with formulas, or by removing the `CHR(13)` and then splitting on the `CHR(10)`.

A formula you can use would be:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(13)&CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),seq_999,999)),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

where `seq_999` is a Named Formula referring to:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*999)
```